# auto.arima MAPE is coming as infinity

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a daily Sales data for around 500 stores. I am trying to fit the ARIMA model in that using the auto.arima function in R. But every time I am running the code, I am getting MAPE either as high as 4000+ or Infinity. Please help me figure out where I am committing the error.

Below mentioned is the snippet of the code

```
# SALES DATA

# Import the Raw Data
raw <- read.delim('clipboard', header=T)
raw.copy <- raw

class(raw) # data.frame
names(raw) # imported properly
sapply(raw, class) 

# Separate out the Dates column
dates <<- as.Date(raw$Dates, format="%m/%d/%y")
raw$Date <- NULL

# Put store sales in a list
storeSales <- lapply(raw, function(x) data.frame(Date=dates, Sales=ts(x, start=c(2012, 3), frequency=365)))

# Accessing data in the list
stats::plot.ts(storeSales[[1]]$Sales)

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# AUTO ARIMA

# Write the function to retrieve autoArima predictions and MAPE values
wmArima <- function(df){ 
modArima <- auto.arima(df$Sales)
p <- predict(modArima, n.ahead=365)
m <- accuracy(modArima)[,'MAPE']
return(list(Predicted=p$pred, MAPE=m))
}

# Call the function and retrieve list of predictions + MAPE scores
ArimaResults <- lapply(storeSales[1:15], wmArima)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to visualize the results or have a look at the true/predicted sales values?

There may be two possibilities about this problem:

1. You have sales values being or close to zero, which will lead to infinite MAPE
2. ARIMA is doing crazy predictions, because of your data or some other factors

It is better to first eliminate the first possibility and then come to SO for help on the second, and a small reproducible example would be very helpful.